# Determine if objects with matching attribute are greater than a variable in ruby array?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array, @items, of ruby objects named Items, which Users purchase.
Items have an attribute 'tier' which can equal 1, 2, or 3.

```
class Item
 def initialize(attributes)
  @price = attributes[:price]
  @tier = attributes[:tier]
 end 
end

class Order
  def initialize
    @items = []
  end

  def receive_gift?
    #number of Items with same tier attribute >= 5
  end
end
```

When 5 Item objects of the same tier are present in the array, a User can receive a free gift. 
How can my receive_gift? method check to see if there are 5 or more of any given Item with the same tier. This is not in rails so I'm not using a DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an `attr_reader` to `items` and `tier`. Then something like this

```
def receive_gift?
  items.group_by(&:tier).any? { |tier, items| items.size >= 5 }
end
```

Or, similar

```
def receive_gift?
  items.group_by(&:tier).values.any? { |items| items.size >= 5 }
end

def receive_gift?
  items.group_by(&:tier).values.map(&:size).max >= 5
end
```

Which tiers does satisfy the condition?

```
def receive_gift?
  items.group_by(&:tier).select { |tier, items| items.size >= 5 }
end
```

Comment: I'll try this! I have attr_readers for all attributes, there are way more methods I haven't included. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: As a follow up, would I be able to access which tier is greater than 5?

Comment: I updated my answer. But please, note that they can be more than one and that the name of the method is now misleading, it doesn't return a boolean anymore.

Comment: Correct, perhaps a different method should return the tier once receive_gift? returns true.